# How to strip a Linux system?

Tags: linux, disk-usage, small-distribution, strip, kiosk

I've been building a Linux distro, and I've stripped the binaries, etc. The system won't use GCC or development tools, as it will be a Chrome kiosk, so it would greatly help if I could strip down the system...

I was wondering, is there a way that I can delete all of the unused system files (like binaries, etc.) by watching what files/libraries are used during runtime? Maybe another method is preferred, but is there a way to accomplish something like this?

Comment: Indeed you are in THE correct place this time :)

Comment: Now, might I ask, why is there a separate Ubuntu-based Stack Exchange site? I think they should merge with this site, because AFAICT, Ubuntu *should* be considered Linux/Unix, but I'm not too sure ;) If not, get ready for GentooOverflow and FedoraOverflow!

Comment: @Blender: This merge was considered and rejected. Look in the two sites' Meta for the history.

Comment: I've found the ubuntu site is a lot more about gnome programs and user interface stuff. Here your answer will almost certainly be a terminal command.

Comment: take a look at busybox for one thing

Comment: I was looking a `busybox`, but I first have to get my tiny X server running, as that takes up the most space. Thanks!

Comment: My understanding is that AskUbuntu is to Unix and Linux as Unix and Linux is to SuperUser: if it's an ubuntu-specific question, it goes to AU; if it's otherwise *n*x-ish, it goes here; otherwise it goes to SU or to ServerFault.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are programs like [Bootchart](http://www.google.com/search?q=linux+startup+graph&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aunofficial&client=firefox-a) that can be used to show what programs you ran during startup - you can probably keep it going after boot to see what's been invoked during a session.

A better solution may be to use remastering tools.

There are remastering tools for [Fedora](http://revisor.fedoraunity.org/), [Ubuntu](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/ubuntu.html), and others; you can use these to customize a distribution.

You might want to look at [Tiny Core Linux](http://www.tinycorelinux.com/). There is a guy working on [a remaster script](http://tinycorelinux.com/forum/index.php?PHPSESSID=5vmt5jpiikqjgshhtfvsfon9k4&topic=677.0) for that as well.

Comment: When I get home, I will definitely try Bootchart. I lied, though, as the system just finished compiling last night, so I'll have to *really* get it running in the next few days. I found TinyX (which is what I was looking for, as I can't figure out what XOrg modules I really need), but the website was down... Oh well, but thank you very much!

Comment: Bootchart it is! I compiled it, ran it, and it gave me extremely verbose and useful results. I'm not going to strip the system *just* yet, as I'm going to implement a source-based package manager (Gentoo?), but I will definitely use this. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Amongst other things, you want to remove *everything* you don't need. Make sure the filesystem has `atime` fully enabled; you can set this in `/etc/fstab`. The current default is `relatime` but you want to use just `atime`. Every time a file is accessed, the timestamp will get updated. Then do some usage for a few days to see which files have never had their atime updated. I would do all of this in a VM, and very carefully, because I imagine there are a few files that are read when the system is in read-only mode. Note: set it to `noatime` once you're ready for production, otherwise you'll do a write every time you read; this is inefficient.

Though to be honest, I'd look at [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/); do you really need to be smaller than that? Build yours based on their distro and simply remove the window manager and a few extra programs. Leave all the command-line tools, that way if you ever need to repair or reload you have the shell.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to do it myself, as I've never really gotten a fully usable LFS system running, but I've played with DLS before. I'm actually trying to build a ChromeOS clone that is not made with SuSEStudio (the one from chromium.org is), and is a bit smaller than 600MB ;) My goal is > 50MB, as DSL includes a ton of other software, but I'm only installing OpenBox, Chrome, and a custom-built Thunar (and some other goodies, of course). Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

*assuming you are using Debian or it's derivatives*

After some days of (heavy) usage, run `popularity-contest`. It will display the oldest unused packages at the bottom. Uninstall those, but with a watchful eye on whether or not there's stuff depending on them installed.

Here's a snippet of the output:

```
1294222606 1292570417 vlc /usr/lib/vlc/plugins/gui/libqt4_plugin.so
1294222606 1292570109 xulrunner-1.9.2 /usr/share/xulrunner-1.9.2/chrome/classic.jar
1294222606 1292507839 ttf-dejavu-extra /usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Oblique.ttf
1294222606 1292507459 x11-utils /usr/bin/xprop
```

The colums mean **atime**, **ctime**, **package-name**, and **file accessed**.

Answer (score 1):

Actively use your system for a while with file access times enabled. See what files never have their access time modified. These are candidates for deletion (but make sure there isn't a reason to keep them, e.g. because they're hardware drivers for hardware you don't have, or they're needed early in the boot process when the root partition is still mounted read-only).

Since you'll have few big applications, check what libraries are used by a single executable. Consider linking them statically.

```
ldd /bin/* /usr/bin/* |sed -n 's/^.* => \(.*\) (.*)$/\1/p' |sort |uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly are you starting from? Are you stripping an existing distro? Is there a reason you have to start with any distro?

You might want to consider building an embedded system from scratch and load only what you know you need.

Comment: I'm building off of a LFS install + Xorg, Python, and Google Chrome. Nothing fancy.

Comment: It used GCC, Python, etc. to build, but they are now obsolete for my purposes.